# Name for generic quantile transform

Tags: data-transformation, terminology, quantiles

Suppose I have two real-valued, continuous random variables, $A$ and $B$, with corresponding cumulative distribution functions $F_A, F_B$ with support $\text{supp}(A), \text{supp}(B)\subseteq \mathbb R$. Consider the map $m : \text{supp}(A) \rightarrow \text{supp}(B)$ defined as
$$ m(x) = F_B^{-1}(F_A(x)) $$
Note that $m(A)$ is distributed like $B$, and all the quantiles align (e.g., the median of $A$ gets mapped to the median of $B$).

This mapping has a name in two special cases: if $B$ is normal, this is apparently called the "normal quantile transformation"; and if $B$ is uniform, then we're just looking at the CDF of $A$.

Is there a term for the transformation when applied to an arbitrary (continuous) $B$?

Comment: Using notation $f$ for density and $F$ for cumulative I would call a very strong convention (not quite a rule). The terminology of _scores_ is common and I think long-standing, but usually with a brand-name for specific cases, so normal scores, uniform scores, exponential scores, logistic scores. But generically? It's a mapping from one quantile function to another, and I don't see that a name is needed beyond that -- and I'm not aware of one.

Comment: Thanks, @NickCox, I've modified my CDF from "f" to "F". As for "score", I'm more accustomed to a separate, unrelated meaning in statistics, per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Score_(statistics) And for my situation, a name for this mapping would be really helpful.

Comment: Indeed: _score_ like many other terms is overloaded. So test scores can be someone's data, factor or component scores are predicted values of new variables, and this is a third sense, and other senses I've forgotten about or never knew would not surprise me.  If there's no standard term that anyone else can recall, then you can devise one. Every term was invented at least once.

Comment: This is the composition of a [probability integral transform](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22probability+integral+transform%22) and its inverse.

Comment: I would propose to call this the *isoquantile* transform. I agree with Nick Cox and whuber that there is no standard term in the literature now.

Comment: I belatedly realize that one can think of this transformation as a *transport map* (in the sense of optimal transport). Of course, it's a trivially simple example.